# XSLT - sum of values of attributes of different nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this code XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy -->
<girone>
    <classifica>
        <squadra nome="Guerrieri" punti="3"/>
        <squadra nome="Indios" punti="5"/>
                <squadra nome="Leoni" punti="4"/>
                <squadra nome="Primula Rossa" punti="1"/>
    </classifica>
    <risultati>
            <partita id="g11">
                     <squadra nome="Indios" goal="2"/>
                     <squadra nome="Guerrieri" goal="0"/>
            </partita>
            <partita id="g12">
                     <squadra nome="Primula Rossa" goal="0"/>
                     <squadra nome="Leoni" goal="3"/>
            </partita>
            <partita id="g13">
                     <squadra nome="Guerrieri" goal="2"/>
                     <squadra nome="Leoni" goal="0"/>
            </partita>
            <partita id="g14">
                     <squadra nome="Indios" goal="1"/>
                     <squadra nome="Primula Rossa" goal="1"/>
            </partita>
            <partita id="g15">
                     <squadra nome="Indios" goal="1"/>
                     <squadra nome="Leoni" goal="1"/>
            </partita>
    </risultati>
</girone>
```

and this code XSLT (a fragment):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:for-each select="girone">
    <xsl:for-each select="risultati/partita/squadra[@nome='Indios']">
           <xsl:value-of select="sum(@goal)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I have to sum all the goals scored by the team "Indios". But instead of getting the result: 4, I get: 211. that is not the sum, but the number of goals (corrected) in sequence.

Also, I should to sum goals conceded of the team "Indios". I had thought like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="girone">
    <xsl:if test="risultati/partita/squadra[@nome='Indios']">
         <xsl:value-of select="sum(risultati/partita/squadra[@nome!='Indios']/@goal)"/>
    </xsl:if>     
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the **xsl:for-each** on the **squadra** elements here. For sum() to work, just put the xpath expression of the nodes you wish to sum inside the sum() function itself, like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="girone">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(risultati/partita/squadra[@nome='Indios']/@goal)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This should give you the answer 4.

EDIT: If you want the goals conceded by 'Indios' in games they have played, the expression will be as follows:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(risultati/partita[squadra[@nome='Indios']]/squadra[@nome!='Indios']/@goal)"/>
```

This gives the result 2.

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer to show this. Please bear in mind this requirement was not mentioned in your original question, so generally speaking you should really edit your question, or ask a whole new question if you have a new problem. Thank you!

Comment: @FrancyGrillo - If this answer is acceptable, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to it.